# Navigaion2 No Local and Global Costmap Publish Issue

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I'm using Navigation2 with ROS Humble on my robot. While I can visualize everything in RViz, the local and global costmaps are not appearing, and I'm getting a "No map received" error. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons might be the map server is not starting correctly or your `global_frame` and `robot_base_frame` at nav2 config file can be wrong. If you can provide more info for example your launch file and config file screenshot of the rviz checking what is wrong with it would be easier.

As a TODO list:

1. Check map server
2. Check tfs (there should be at least a map frame and base_link frame)
3. Check nav2 config file